# Match a literal string but allow certain characters to be missing

Tags: regex

**In the end I decided to strip out the invalid characters from the "haystack" as this is not possible with standard regex**

I have to capture the following `"Capture... Test: Something",` the literal string I have to match with is `"Capture... Test Something"`

The issue is that the match failed due to : missing, the : could be one of a few characters `(*, /, ?, :, ", <, >, |)` that have been previously stripped out from the literal string `"Capture... Test Something"`

How would I allow the capture of a literal string but allow the few characters listed above not to match?

Note: The only thing I can to use to match with is `"Capture... Test Something"`, and In the end I need to return a match of `"Capture... Test: Something"`

I'm unable to modify "Capture... Test Something"

I'm trying to use http://kodi.wiki/view/Scrapers to match for a title

Comment: @anubhava: Sadly that will not work, I am unable to modify "Capture... Test Something"

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you remove the `:`, it's no longer there. You can't determine if it was ever there unless you have the original string. Nor can you simply insert `:` in your match: you don't know if it was originally there. Forcibly inserting it, regardless of whether it was originally there, effectively simply means `return haveMatch ? "Capture... Test: Something" : null;`, without actually determining what was matched. You have to let go of at least one of your requirements.

Comment: @hvd I'm trying to match `"Capture... Test: Something"` but the only thing I have to work with is `"Capture... Test Something"` without modifying that string I can do anything around it.

Comment: You can make a copy of that string and modify the copy?

Comment: @Understalker But you don't know if your `"Capture... Test Something"` was originally `"Capture... Test: Something"`, yet you say you need to return that as your match, presumably only if it originally really was `"Capture... Test: Something"`. Even without thinking about writing the code, how would you do this? Given `"Capture... Test Something"` and `"Capture... Test Something"`, how could you possibly determine that the first had a `:` in it that has since been removed, and the second doesn't?

Comment: @Understalker Based on your edit, I think you don't actually need to return any match, you simply need to determine whether there is a match, and return true or false accordingly. Is that correct?

Comment: @hvd Well the end goal is to match `"Capture... Test: Something"` by using `"Capture... Test Something"`

I have added more information to the end of the question for the usage behind all of this.

Comment: Are you looking for a fuzzy match? Like what Google does?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an input string to match against, you can construct a regular expression out of it, by first escaping the string, and then putting optional quantifiers after the characters you want to make optional:

```
var search = "Capture... Test: Something";
var input = "Capture... Test Something";

search = Regex.Escape(search);
search = Regex.Replace(search, @"[*/?:""<>|]", "$0?");

var match = Regex.Match(input, search);
```

Check the [demo here](http://ideone.com/nHTOmx).

Another approach would be to strip all the optional characters from both strings and then check these:

```
var search = "Capture... Test: Something";
var input = "Capture... Test Something";

search = Regex.Replace(search, @"[*/?:""<>|]", string.Empty);
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"[*/?:""<>|]", string.Empty);

var index = input.IndexOf(search);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/eC2xbb)